# Мягкое "ц" в "Интернационале" - откуда?

Tags: фонетика, история

Если поискать "Интернационал" на Ютубе, верхние ответы поиска показывают одну и ту же запись - например, [раз](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjIewby4k0Y), [два](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8EMx7Y16Vo). Она характерна тем, что фраза припева "С «Интернационалом» воспрянет род людской" выпевается с мягким "ц".

Запись не может быть старой (я не нашёл точного времени, но вряд ли раньше 1950-х, качество достаточно хорошее). Откуда эта особенность, это характерно для какого-то временного периода, или индивидуальность какого-то авторитетного источника?

Comment: Может это особенность именно пения?

Comment: @Буратино

А как вам это: https://dedmazai.livejournal.com/645959.html   И еще вопрос: Вы какой звук после Ц произносите в обычной речи, точно ли ЦЫ?  Слог-то безударный, редукция значительная, произносится то, что легче выговаривается. Мне кажется, что я говорю ЦЭ.  Ну а в песне будет скорее ЦЫ.

Comment: я говорю цы или ци. При пении могут звуки смягчаться и оглушаться, и произноситься не совсем так, техника пения не дает прерывать звук, если делать акцент на звуке как во время обычной речи или декламации, он будет слишком выпячиваться. Возможно, это может влиять. Вообще, правильно редуцировать до ц+краткое ы, а не до э.

Answer (score 0):

В древнерусском языке и шипящие, и «ц» были мягкими. Твердым «ц»  стал в XVI в.
Современный русский (твердый)  «ц» мы имеем только в окончаниях (шлепанцы, бубенцы, смуглолицый), суффиксах (сестр-иц-ын, кур-иц-ын) и в корнях слов – исключений.
Твердому «ц» сознательно противопоставлялся (и противопоставляется) полумягкий западноевропейский -ц'- (ср. франц. station — 'станция', нем. musizieren — 'музицировать').
На письме буква «и» маркирует слова-заимствования с «нерусским» [ц'] типа: цинк, порции-он-н-ый, наци-он-альн-ый...
https://sci.house/grafika-orfografiya-fonetika-scibook/variantnyie-bukvosochetaniya-tsi-85035.html
На мой взгляд, слова нация и интернационал по сию пору озвучиваются мягким «ц», чего уже не стану утверждать в отношении слова «нацист».

Answer (score 0):

Потому что "ц" смягчает "ь", не

*с Интернац**и**оналом*, а *с Интернац**ь**оналом*,

так убирают лишний слог.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]